# PHP: Send $_POST data to my Class?

Tags: php, http-post

I'm trying to send my $_POST data to a class of mine for processing... but it doesn't seem to matter how I send it, PHP is telling me:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Class method:

```
public function test_me_out($postdata) {

    if(isset($postdata->price)) {

        return "the price was: " . $postdata->price . " …and this was added.";

    } else {

        return "it's apparently not set...";

    }

}
```

Comment: It has dawned on me that the post data, is not an object, but even if I create an array out of it and try to access it that way, same result.

Comment: Try `test_me_out((object)$_POST);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is not an object. You should access its information using it as an array like `$_POST['my_data']`.

Comment: doesn't that mean that I should be able to access it in my class like: `$postdata['price']`?

Answer (score 2):

You can still do

```
$postData = new ArrayObject($_POST,ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
```

Then `$postData->price` will work as expected to be.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling test_me_out? Like this?

```
test_me_out($_POST)
```

$_POST is an array, not an object. Therefore you can access the variables in your function like so:

```
$postdata['price']
```